# Automatically build client dlls dependent on current one

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

Say I have a large VC++ solution with many projects. When I build DLL A, is there any way to ask VC to automatically build all dlls/programs that are dependent on A (i.e., by its import library) when A's build is complete?

I can build the whole solution to achieve this if everything has been built(especially those projects not dependent on A). But in my case some projects independent on A haven't been build yet (and I definitely don't want to build them!).

So is there any way to build this dependency chain from A?

Comment: Not directly as far as I know, but you could for instance parse the .sln file to figure out the dependent projetcs and have a post-build event to build just those.

Comment: OK, that's one step further than what I'm doing;) Thought it's not an uncommon job for vc to handle it already.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's common enough that there's a built-in way. Anyway, another solution is to have a seperate .sln with just the projects depending on A. Or unload everything not depending on A then build.

Comment: @stijn I'd prefer the 1st option as it adapts to change, if a new project depends on A in future (likely, A is a utility dll)